# WP Post web-pages shows index content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

As an amateur WordPress developer i'm trying my luck with my first template, I came across this issue where when ever i access a Post web-page i get the content of the Index.php file. this seems to appear only with Posts web-pages, as this problem does not appear with the Page web-pages. As for now my template contain the following files:

> footer.php , function.php , header.php , index.php , page.php

Am i missing a file that should handle the Posts type? if not what could lead to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing single.php to handle individual post pages.

Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/ for some more info on the main template files.

Comment: thank you. you may have clue why posts ids are skipping? creating two posts one right after another takes the id's 19 and than 21. why is it happening?

Comment: The ids relate to entries in the db - and many thing can go in there as well as posts - like revision etc... if you really want to see what is going on take a look at the wp_posts table and you can see what too up the 20 spot.